# Anchors for page url/treemenu

Tags: kentico

I have created a page that contains many anchors. In the cmstree, under that page I have created pages that reflect those anchors. First, on the sub pages, what is the best way to set the url to simply be #AnchorA and #AnchorB? Second, I would assume I will do a custom query to append the anchor to the end of the parent page url...correct?

In the cmstree, I have:

Item

- AnchorA
- AnchorB

Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear on what you are trying to do but here is the suggestion based on some assumption.

For something like this structure

Chapter Page (parent)

- Section A page (#sctA)
- Section B page (#sctB)
- Section C page (#sctC)

On the Chapter Page, you can use a Repeater to display all 3 section pages. Within the transformation, you can insert anchor tags before the display of each section.

For Creating links to 3 sections, use another repeater and the transformation will just be something like

```
<a href="#{% DocumentName %}" >{% DocumentName %}</a>
```